# How to validate getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity cognito token

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am building an authentication system using aws lambdas, dynamodb and cognito.

Am stuck at comparing the token provided from the getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(); call with one from the server for the specific identity.

Am getting the token and identity with:

```
function getToken(email, fn) {
    var param = {
        IdentityPoolId: cognitoIdentityPoolId,
        Logins: {} // To have provider name in a variable
    };
    param.Logins[cognitoDeveloperProvidedName] = email;
    cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(param,
        function(err, data) {
            if (err) return fn(err); // an error occurred
            else fn(null, data.IdentityId, data.Token); // successful response
        });
}
```

Then as far as I understand it I can get the already generated token from cognito (not create a new one) like this:

```
function checkToken(IdentityId, email, fn){
    var param = {
        IdentityPoolId: cognitoIdentityPoolId,
        IdentityId: IdentityId,
        Logins: {}
    };
    param.Logins[cognitoDeveloperProvidedName] = email;
    cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(param, 
        function(err, data) {
            if (err) return fn(err);
            else fn(null, data);
        });
}
```

But I can't seem to get it to work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out, the checkToken function needs to look like this:

```
function checkToken(providedIdentity, token, fn){
    var param = {
        IdentityId: providedIdentity,
        Logins: {}
    };
    param.Logins['cognito-identity.amazonaws.com'] = token;
    cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(param, 
        function(err, data) {
            if (err) return fn(err);
            else fn(null, data);
        });
}
```

I needed to set cognito-identity.amazonaws.com as the login provider

Comment: Yes, once you get the cognito token, the provider is now cognito-identity.amazonws.com, as you discovered.

Comment: Wasn't very clear in the docs, had to find an example written in Java to figure it out, hope someone finds this post and saves the 3 hours I spent on it.

Comment: Hi @MarkMercurio and Cub3. Can you clarify if this checkToken function is for checking the token when it comes from a client? I mean that if the token is generated in a login API method (using getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity) and the token is sent to a client, then the client calls to other methods by using this token, so it is needed a token validation by using getCredentialsForIdentity.  Is this correct? Should I store the user's identityId in my database? Thank you in advance